# Do units get the "multiple unit bonus" from Warlords?

Tags: talisman-thh

I seem to be creating a new tag, this is for Talisman:  The Horus Heresy.

I moved to a sector where my Loyalist Warlord would be attacked by a Close Combat 4 unit if he encountered the sector.  I'd actually meant to encounter the enemy Warlord there, who only had a Close Combat of 4 as well, meaning to try to get him injured and on the run, but accidentally clicked Encounter Sector.  No matter, the experience from the CC 4 demons unit (not a dataslate, in case it matters - one of the squares that always attacks Loyalists) would be enough to give me another point of CC....  until the fight started and the generic unit had a +3 to Close Combat!

Needless to say, I lost, even on the re-roll.  But where does a generic unit get a +3?  Does the Warlord add to generic unit rolls in the same sector?  I checked his character card, he doesn't have a power like that, but I could be misunderstanding a rule somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having several more hours of play under my belt now, I can say this is normal behavior.  Warlords add +3 to allied Warlords and Units (whether those Units are the same Legion and regardless of if those Units are Dataslates or not) in the same Region, it seems.